# Provide a subset of the current theme settings page

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a way to provide a subset of:

```
admin/build/themes/settings/<theme_name>
```

on a different path.

THEMEHOOK_settings doesn't appear to offer the necessarily granularity.

Ideally I would achieve this without re-implementing any of the theme subsystem.

Is there a way that I can pass the results from my own form into the theme system such that the configurations are saved in much the same way as THEMEHOOK settings is doing under the hood?

I'm happy to clarify if need be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to [Creating advanced theme settings](http://drupal.org/node/177868). This step you through every step you need to add your own form to the theme settings page.

Comment: I'm not looking to override the existing theme settings. If I was I could use ThemeHook_settings and be done with it.  I'm interested in creating an alternative and more restrictive theme settings tool. I'm coming to the conclusion that this is not something Drupal is well equipped to do out of the box.